# Select WPF DataTemplate that is determined by type of object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, datatemplate

I have a ViewModel that has a List of objects that have the same interface and to show them in the view we have a list of `UserControl`s in our view model that the view binds to. I was wondering if I could create a template for the different types of concrete objects in the list and have WPF apply the correct one for me instead of creating the `UserControl` list and binding to that.

Basically I have:

```
<StackPanel 
            Margin="0,0,20,0"
            >                
            <my2:ProfileIdentificationView />
            <ItemsControl
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProfileSections}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
```

Where the ItemsSource binding is the list of user controls. I am looking for a way to apply the look of those UserControls here based on the type of the ProfileSection. Like one type is an IIS section and another Type is a Users section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create implciit `DataTemplates` for your view models via the [`DataTemplate.DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx). Make sure to use the `x:Type` markup extensions as strings are interpreted as XML-element tags (to allow implicit templating of XML).

Comment: So for this all I need to do then is define the templates in my resources section and they will be applied automatically?

Comment: @twreid: It's quite convenient, i tend to let the application create such implicit templates via reflection wiring up view models with their respective views.

Comment: Yea I am going through and changing some of the custom controls we had created to this and it makes my life a lot easier binding directly to a list of viewmodels instead of a list of UserControls. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the importance of x:Type markup extension. I was missing it and when added it everything worked well.